# Detecting laptop lid close in X11 (at least for Xorg/Linux)

Tags: linux, x11, xorg

I'm looking for an API that would allow an X11 application to find out when/whether the laptop lid is closed, at least on Linux with not-too-ancient Xorg.

(Preferably something that doesn't require libraries of the sort that [wouldn't be safe to use in xscreensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/toolkits.html).)

Comment: I may be over my paygrade here since I haven't done any X _programming_, but X uses [Display Power Management Signaling](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/dpms.html) in conjunction with ACPI events from the kernel to do this AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something that listens on DBUS for such events (as specified by freedesktop.org)? Try https://github.com/airtonix/laptop-lid-event-listener/blob/master/dbus-laptop-lid-listener.py

Comment: Hmm, that seems to need HAL? It looks like that's been superseded by UPower in this area...